# Can I restrict what biomes appear in my world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Ok, so for the last few worlds I have created, I did a bit of exploring, and so far the norm has been:

- Plains
- Forest
- Birch Forest
- Hills
- (If I'm lucky) A Swamp

These seem to be the only biomes that want to spawn in my world. I can find others, *if* I go searching for them (flying about in creative).

Basically, I'm sick of this world generation. I want a bit more diversity in my worlds, so I was wondering what can I do to open up a bit more of a biome diversity in my world? Eg. restrict what biomes do/don't spawn?

Comment: In the customised world type, you can restrict it to just the one biome of your choice, but that isn't exactly what you're looking for I assume.

Comment: Not really, if anything it's a bit of the opposite.

Comment: Have you tried making the biomes smaller? Less distance to travel, more variety.

Comment: That is a possibility, but I'm just so sick of these Birch Forests and Hills!! Haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this may not be what you are looking for, Mods are a great way to do this.
World Generation is limited by what the game allows, so if you want to change how the world is created, you need to change the World Generation, which is probably not easy. Using a Mod can that changes this is the easiest way. Mods such as Biomes-O-Plenty add dozens of Biomes, and some (possibly Biomes-o-plenty, as i don't recall) also allow you to customize the variables so you can enable or disable certain Biomes, or even modify the size or frequency, often times in easy to modify text based files.

All you really have to do is pick one of the many free mod clients, and pick the mods you want. You may have to pick a large Mod pack however, and disable or deselect all the mods except for a few that you actually want if you want as close to vanilla as possible.

Answer (score -3):

i found a seed in which they have all the Biomes that you wanted and it doesnt have any junggle or dessert biomes. i've tried to find one on creative mode, been flying around till i reach 24000,(), 24000 still no dessert or jungle. here's the seed if you want: -1237332647 by the way this is an infinite world type.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your contribution, however this does not answer the question. I understand that it is possible to find a seed to meet my requirements, however I was asking if it was possible to create a world that generates a seed, every time.