# What biomes spawn where?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I recently asked a question about [restricting which biomes appear in my world](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242348/can-i-restrict-what-biomes-appear-in-my-world) and I was wondering if there was a system or something similar that determined which biomes spawned in which order.

For example, Swamp biomes only seem to spawn between either Plains/Forest biomes, and Ocean biomes. Whereas Savannah biomes only seem to spawn close to Desert (and possibly Mesa) biomes.

Is there a system that determines where each biomes spawn? If so, what is it?

Comment: They get grouped according to their general climate for realism, but that's about all I can tell you. I might do some research and see if I can post an answer sometime in the next few days.

Comment: I don't think there is an "order" for biomes to spawn. Minecraft also doesn't really care about realism. I already saw desert next to a jungle. And next to that desert there was a tundra. So I think this is more or less random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all biomes in Minecraft fit into one the following categories:

- Snow-covered
- Cold
- Medium/lush
- Dry/warm
- Neutral

Here's a table I made showing which category each biome falls into:

[image: Biome table]

Biomes in the same category generate near each other in clumps, so it's more likely to find a Mesa next to a Savanna rather than next to a Taiga, for example. This biome clumping can be seen on zoomed out world maps:

[image: World map with admist]

The ocean biomes, which don't fit into a category, are usually used to separate the biome clumps from eachother, but it's still common to get two different biome clumps connected to eachother by land, and thus you'll sometimes see biomes from different categories adjacent to eachother.